# Laravel 5.3 Auth Session Not Working

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I did the Laravel update from 5.2 to 5.3 and when I put it on the server came the surprise, the sessions were not working ...

I already tried to do some things, but all to no avail ....

Web routes file

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    Route::get('auth/facebook', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');
    Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Authentication file

```
 /**
 * Obtain the user information from Facebook.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback() 

{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
$authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

$id = $authUser['id'];
$email = $authUser['email'];
$password = $authUser['senha'];

$credentials = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'excluded' => 0);
Auth::attempt($credentials);
Auth::loginUsingId($id);
```

If i run dd( Auth::user() ); the auth is working, but after the redirect the session is lose

Kernel file

```
<?php
namespace App\Http;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];
    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this i change the file session.php

Look for

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session'
```

And change to

```
'cookie' => 'app_session',
```

After it every works fine

Comment: obviously, this wouldn't make a difference and did not work

Answer (score 0):

> The answer below is not working.

When I upgraded to version 5.3 I needed to move the routes file and found that I needed to remove the web middleware line and this problem started ...

I just readjusted the line and it's working now.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('auth/facebook', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');
    Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```